# type-parametrized object in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types

Is there a way to write object with generic parameters, like that:

```
object Aaa[T] {
   def f(a: T) = a
}
```

Or, in other words, to have singleton on instance-level, but not on the type level.

I know that I could do the same with:

```
object Aaa {
   def f[T](a: T) = a
}
```

But what if I have several methods to restrict with single polymorphic type:

```
object Aaa[T] {
   def f1(a: T) = a
   def f2(b: T) = b
}

//somewhere in the code:
val a = Aaa[Int]
import a._

f1(5)
f2(6)
someFunction(a)
```

P.S. All I want is singleton factory with type-parameter as input (and as a key). Usually it's implemented with `Map[TypeTag, Object]` (which requires thread-safety, btw) - looking for more nice solution here. For example with "parametrize method" approach I can't:

```
trait T1[T] {
   def f1(a: T): T
   def f2(b: T): T
}

object Aaa extends T1 { //won't compile, have to use class
   //some heavy initialization and data here
   (1 to 100500000).map(List.empty[T]) 
   def f1[T](a: T) = a
   def f2[T](b: T) = b
}
```

It might be some method that creates a big structure and requires generic type to be specified.

And of course this object may be passed to another function (or value), so single polymorphic type restriction really works.

Comment: Despite the fact that this is a self-answered question (you obviously already have the solution you want), I still want to point out why this is bad style. Declaring a parameterized trait / class implies that the type parameter is fixed for any given instance. However, all of your method definitions are actually independent of any top-level type. You're saving yourself from typing a couple of characters at the cost of muddying your definitions with a confusing level of indirection. My suggestion: _just use find/replace in your editor to add the `[T]` all at once!_

Comment: first - [It's OK to answer own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: `all of your method definitions are actually independent of any top-level type` - how is that? Btw it's not just `Aaa[Int].f(5);Aaa[Int].f(6) `, I may pass this object everywhere, I may save it to the value and import it: `val a = Aaa[Int]; import a._`

Comment: "Top-level type" probably wasn't the best choice of words. I simply meant (based on the fact that you _can_ declare all the methods as `f1[T]`, `f2[T]`, etc) that your definitions do not depend on any class/trait-level type parameters. By moving the `[T]` to an external trait and then doing this "trick" you are obfuscating how the object works for the sake of saving a few characters in your object definition. In my opinion, that's a very poor software engineering choice.

Comment: @DaoWen 2)  My definitions are depend on same `type T`, which will be passed on the type level, You can't `Aaa[List[Int]].f(5)` for example. As I shown in previous comment you can: `val a = Aaa[Int]; import a._` and then every method will be dependent **exactly** on `Int`. And what is really matter you can pass this object to the function (as I shown in the answer). 1) This is just singleton factory with parameterized by type (all polymorphic instances of `Aaa` are sharing same address independently from type). I still see nothing bad about it. People usually do it with Maps and typetags

Comment: In that case, it probably makes more sense to just declare this as a class (not an object) and actually use new instances for your different types. After all, [that's what they do with TypeTags](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1819af77fd4ecc66c89a84ea321aa7d6f92285ec/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/TypeTags.scala#L268). The overhead is negligible, and the code is much cleaner.

Comment: @DaoWen About your TypeTags link I could did that by `object IntAaa extends Aaa[Int]; object DoubleAaa ...` (no TypeTags needed), but I don't know all possible types actually, that's the point.

Comment: @DaoWen  
If you really think that TypeTags implementation of this factory is much simpler than asInstanceOf (I actually did such and there is also `asInstanceOf` :) ) - I have nothing to say. Just make your own answer with same examples as I've shown. About overhead - it takes `CountOfPossiblePassedTypes`(that are unknnown!) times more cpu/memory than this, + requiring warming-up to prevent first-long-call (we had a restriction for maximum time of processing for every message)

Comment: the only critics I could find is that my solution may require VM with type erasure (so restricted to the JVM :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible using `.asInstanceOf`:

```
trait AaaImpl[T] {
   this: Aaa.type =>
   def f(a: T) = a
}

object Aaa extends AaaImpl[Nothing] { // lower bound of T should be here
   def apply[T] = this.asInstanceOf[AaaImpl[T]]
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait AaaImpl
defined module Aaa

scala> Aaa[Int].f(5)
res7: Int = 5

scala> Aaa[Double].f(5.0)
res8: Double = 5.0
```

It's safe to cast here as long as your object doesn't do any other typecasts. `asInstanceOf` just copying your type (using `AaaImpl[Nothing]` as prototype) but with new type parameter (like `case class`'s `copy` does in values world).

P.S. Trait's methods will be also available inside Aaa itself, but `Nothing` will be used for `T`

P.S.2 You may also implement some other traits to pass this object to some external library:

```
//External
trait SomeAbstractType[T] {
   def f(a: T): T
}

def ff[T](x: SomeAbstractType[T]) = x

//Internal
trait AaaImpl[T] { def f(a: T) = a }

object Aaa extends AaaImpl[Nothing] with SomeAbstractType[Nothing] { // lower bound of T should be here
   def apply[A] = this.asInstanceOf[AaaImpl[A] with SomeAbstractType[A]]
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait SomeAbstractType
ff: [T](x: SomeAbstractType[T])SomeAbstractType[T]
defined trait AaaImpl
defined module Aaa

scala> ff(Aaa[Int])
res11: SomeAbstractType[Int] = Aaa$@6e18a830

scala> ff(Aaa[Double])
res12: SomeAbstractType[Double] = Aaa$@6e18a830 //same instance

scala> ff(Aaa[Int]).f(5) //different behaviour
res15: Int = 5

scala> ff(Aaa[Double]).f(5.0)
res16: Double = 5.0
```

Update1. Examples of something cooler than identity:

```
scala> trait AaaImpl[T] {
   def list(a: T) = List(a)
   def empty = List[T]()
   def square(a:T)(implicit n:Numeric[T]) = n.times(a, a)
}
defined trait AaaImpl

scala> object Aaa extends AaaImpl[Nothing]{ // lower bound of T should be here
   def apply[A] = this.asInstanceOf[AaaImpl[A]]
}
defined module Aaa

scala> Aaa[Int].list(5)
res21: List[Int] = List(5)

scala> Aaa[Int].empty
res22: List[Int] = List()

scala> Aaa[Int].square(5)
res23: Int = 25

scala> Aaa[List[Int]].square(5)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(5)
 required: List[Int]
              Aaa[List[Int]].square(5)
                                    ^
```

Comment: Do you have examples of other stuff you can safely do with this besides provide an identity function?

Comment: I suppose, everything you could do  inside `trait` - create `List(a)` for example

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the benefit. You traded the addition of `[T]` to a limited number of methods to writing `Aaa[T]` whenever you use `Aaa`?

Comment: @ Ionuț G. Stan See my comments to the question, in short: "this object may be passed to another function or value" `val a = Aaa[Int]; import a._` - just as first example. P.S. This is scala guys :), why should I explain everything that possible to do here :). I actually had a problem with heavy singleton requiring type-parameters - initially solved it with `Map[TypeTag, Aaa]` (concurrent Map by the way), then came up with better solution.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan and did you see my example with `def ff: [T](x: SomeAbstractType[T])` , my "P.S." in the question - the signature of the method (and `SomeAbstractType` interface ) requires `def f` to not take any type parameters.

Comment: @Travis Brown I've added some examples